# LiveConnect functionality for desktop application - no API?

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-live, outlook.com

I'm trying to connect to outlook.com via the Live Connect-API. This however only seems to be for WP8 and Windows 8 devices. What shall I do to access outlook.com (delete calendar &import a .ics file) from a Windows 7 desktop?

Is there some neat API hidden in some namespace? Things like `LiveConnectClient` don't seem to be available. Or do I have to do the raw REST calls myself? Is there some tutorial?